# Looking for a photoshop script to add text to image and resize to fit

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I have a psd file with two text layers.

I would like to add a quote in the first text layer and a name in the second.

The data is coming from a csv.

The quotes can vary in length. The font size for the "quote" text layer therefor needs to be set to fit within the text box.

I tried scripting it for the better part of the day now and am stumped.

Thank you!

Comment: this might help you https://www.google.ie/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=freelance%20programmer%20to%20hire&oq=freelance%20programmer%20to%20hire&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4527j0j8

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with? A basic approach or some specific line of code?  I have done similar tasks in PS - it is scriptable but it isn't straightforward or pretty.  Essentially I had to guess and test.  Adjust the font size, rasterize a copy of the text layer and check its bounds. Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not Photoshop, you might want to check out Templater for After Effects which lets you dynamically insert data into layers.  Templater also comes with layout logic that allows you to determine the fitting of various lengths of text and resolutions of source images.

The data can come from a tabbed-separated value file or from a Google Sheets document.  Even though it works for After Effects, you can use Templater to export still images from AE.

Learn more at http://dataclay.com